# How to setup Mac OS X terminal as VScode?

Tags: vim, terminal, dynamics-business-central

I develop for D365 Business Central, I use VSCode which has an extension to develop apps for it.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dynamics-smb.al

Having installed the above VSCode extension, connecting to a SaaS sandbox, which is simply writing the config flags of in a Launch.json file which is part of the app's file structure, I develop for D365 Business Central.

Recently I have been wanting to write/edit, deploy and debug in Mac OS X terminal itself. Avoiding using VScode. I have no idea where to begin to eventually have a complete setup in the terminal itself of developing apps for D365 Business Central not touching VSCode.

I need guidance, please share how do I start this. I do know first I have to choose an editor, VIM maybe? and then figure out how to place files that get downloaded from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dynamics-smb.al somewhere accessible in Terminal? Because that is what will give me autosuggests of functions etc like it does in VScode?

Comment: The VSCode extension will most certainly not work in Vim... I don't really know what D365 BC is, but unless you have access to the standalone build tools and a deep understanding of how the pieces work together (or someone who does put together Vim plug-ins to do that), I'd say you'll have a very hard time... My 2c: just stick with VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only use VSCode, the compiler and the build tools are not standalone
(I feel your pain, I'm coming from vim)

Cheers